# Can't figure out how to fit content on 2 columns

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to fit content on 2 columns, to display it correctly. 
I would like the content (later will be several images, 6+) on two columns, centred on each of them.

I tried with the code above but I'm looking for something more appropriate for my case.

```css
.portfolio-column {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 40px;
  column-width: 100px;
}

.box1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-bg3" id="portfolio">
  <a href=""></a>
  <p class="portfolio">Portfolio</p>
  <div class="portfolio-column">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/nakata/pen/rJdKOK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `column-count`, you don't need to use inner `div`s to make them as columns.
Be sure to display images as `block` and use `margin:auto;` to easily center them horizontally.

```css
.portfolio-box {
  position: relative;
  column-count: 2;
}
.portfolio-box img{
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-bg3" id="portfolio">
  <a href=""></a>
  <p class="portfolio">Portfolio</p>
  <div class="portfolio-box">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgFrB.png" />
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgFrB.png" />
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgFrB.png" />
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgFrB.png" />
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgFrB.png" />
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgFrB.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

That way, the only property to modify is `column-count` in the CSS to modify the display.

```css
.portfolio-box {
  position: relative;
  column-count: 3;
}
.portfolio-box img{
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-bg3" id="portfolio">
  <a href=""></a>
  <p class="portfolio">Portfolio</p>
  <div class="portfolio-box">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgFrB.png" />
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgFrB.png" />
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgFrB.png" />
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgFrB.png" />
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgFrB.png" />
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgFrB.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```